# How to create a hash from a multidimensional array

Tags: ruby, hash

I have these params :

```
x=["room_adults_1", "room_childs_1", "room_adults_2", "room_childs_2"]
```

And when I run this code:

```
y = x.map { |x| x.match(/^(room)_(adults|childs)_(\d+)/)}
z = y.map { |x| [x[1],[x[2],[x[3].reverse,""]]]}
```

I get this array:

```
 => [["room", ["adults", ["1", ""]]], ["room", ["childs", ["1", ""]]], ["room", ["adults", ["2", ""]]], ["room", ["childs", ["2", ""]]]]
```

I would like to transform this last result into a Hash. If I use `z.to_h` (collapse last element), I obtain `{"room"=>["childs", ["2", ""]]}`. But I would like a Hash like this:

```
 {
    "room":{
     "adults":{[
      {"1": ""},
      {"2": ""}
     ]},
     "child":{[
      {"1": ""},
      {"2": ""}
     ]} 
    }
  }
```

How can I do?

Comment: @lcguida ... stackoverflow e l'inglese :P

Comment: The hash you want is not a hash. It's not a valid Ruby object.

Comment: For "child/adults":{[...]} ?

Comment: `{[{"1": ""}, {"2": ""}]}` is `{arr}` where `arr = [{"1": ""}, {"2": ""}]`, but `{arr}` is not a valid object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x.map { |e| e.split '_' }
 .group_by(&:shift) # room
 .map { |k, v| [k, v.group_by(&:shift) # adults/children
                    .map { |k, v| [k, v.map { |e, *| {e => ""} } ] }
                    .to_h ] }
 .to_h

#⇒ {"room"=>{"adults"=>[{"1"=>""}, {"2"=>""}],
#            "childs"=>[{"1"=>""}, {"2"=>""}]}}
```

Comment: excellent answer although `dup` is not needed since `map` will return a copy anyway. Also I would put the dots on the end of the previous lines so that this is actual code

Comment: You're a genius :D

Comment: The "x" variable coming from Params. For assign the correct value to hash, use: params["room_#{k}_#{f.first}"]

Comment: @engineersmnky dots are allowed to be on the next line. `dup` is redundant here, yes, thanks, removed.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I don't understand your reference to the placement of the dots. What Muddie has now looks fine, though IRB will choke on it.

Comment: @mudasobwa my fault on the dots should have worded my comment **much much** better I simply meant so that it could be copied directly into IRB.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I prefer `each_with_object`:

```
x = ["room_adults_1", "room_childs_1", "room_adults_2", "room_childs_2"]

export = x.each_with_object(Hash.new { |k, v| k[v] = Hash.new { |k, v| k[v] = [] } }) do |string, exp|
  room, type, id = string.split("_")
  exp[room][type] << {id => ""}
end

p export
# => {"room"=>{"adults"=>[{"1"=>""}, {"2"=>""}], "childs"=>[{"1"=>""}, {"2"=>""}]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume the desired result is

```
{:room=>{:adults=>[{:"1"=>""}, {:"2"=>""}], :childs=>[{:"1"=>""}, {:"2"=>""}]}}
```

as the construct given in the question is not a valid Ruby object, let alone a hash.

```
arr = ["room_adults_1", "room_childs_1", "room_adults_2", "room_childs_2"]

h = arr.map { |s| s.split('_')[1,2].map(&:to_sym) }.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {:adults=>[[:adults, :"1"], [:adults, :"2"]],
  #    :childs=>[[:childs, :"1"], [:childs, :"2"]]}

{ room: h.merge(h) { |k,a,_| a.map { |_,b| { b=>"" } } } }
  #=> {:room=>{:adults=>[{:"1"=>""}, {:"2"=>""}], :childs=>[{:"1"=>""}, {:"2"=>""}]}}
```

If the keys are to be strings, not symbols, remove `.map(&:to_sym)`.